# Как ввести текст в поле ввода другой программы?

Tags: c++, winapi

Подскажите, каким образом можно ввести текст в поле ввода другой программы?
Определил HWND, но как дальше найти поле ввода и вставить туда текст?

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм примерно такой:

1. Используя функцию [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx) и знание о том, что поле ввода имеет класс "EDIT", находим HWND поля ввода. Можно использовать дополнительные критерии, чтобы отличить одно поле ввода от другого, поисследуйте интересующую вас программу при помощи Spy++.
2. Посылаем полю ввода сообщение [WM_SETTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644(v=vs.85).aspx).

Я, правда, уже лет 7 не сталкивался с WinAPI, пусть знатоки меня поправят, если я где-то бред написал.

Comment: А можно просто сэмулировать нажатия клавиши

Comment: @Garden Chamber чтобы просто сэмулировать нажатие клавиши, нужно сначала всё равно сделать всё из пункта 1, чтобы сфокусировать поле ввода